# How can I access query results in php where I'm returning values AS things? (Rather than looking at fields)

Tags: php, mysql

*Apologies, I can't think of how to phrase this better (which has the additional problem of making it more difficult to research an answer, too). Suggestions for editing terms for clarity are more than welcome.*

I am running two queries on a table in my database. The first simply returns all results within certain constraints imposed by the user - I'm echoing this out to a table with no problems at all. The second returns a `COUNT` and a `SUM` AS things, which I am having trouble accessing and echoing to the screen.

First Query -

```
$results = $connection->query(" SELECT `Date`, `Test`, `Errors` ... ");
while($result = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $result['Date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $result['Test'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $result['Errors'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This works perfectly well. As expected, it echos out a table with the results in each row.

Second Query -

```
    $totals = $connection-query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tests, SUM(`Errors`) AS TotalErrors ... "); 

echo "<th>Total Tests</th>"; 
echo "<td>" . $totals['Tests'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<th>Total Errors</th>"; 
echo "<td>" . $totals['TotalErrors'] . "</td>";
```

I cannot seem to access the values in the second query to echo them to the screen.

I have tried using var_dump to ensure the query is returning results correctly, and it is. If I use `var_dump($totals->fetch_assoc());` it will display `array(2) { ["Tests"]=> string(2) "33" ["TotalErrors"]=> string(1) "9" }`, as expected.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, looking at my syntax, it seems the same as when I access the values from the first query, but I'm not sure if it should be different because I am returning values AS rather than looking at field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tests, SUM(`Errors`) AS TotalErrors ... "); 
$totals = $results->fetch_assoc();
echo "<th>Total Tests</th>; 
echo "<td>" . $totals['Tests'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<th>Total Errors</th>"; 
echo "<td>" . $totals['TotalErrors'] . "</td>";
```